# Invalid argument supplied for foreach in PHP,

Tags: php, pdo, invalidargumentexception

I am running a PDO query on a MySQL database and I get an error saying there is invalid argument supplied for the foreach. On the frontend, I just pass a string to $questionTable and an integer for $questionID.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$query = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM ('$questionTable') WHERE id = ('$questionID')");
foreach ($query as $row) {
 echo $row;
};
```

Comment: What is the value of `$query`? What api is used - PDO or mysqli or else?

Comment: You need to get the result set of the query to iterate the rows in your loop. You are expected to do some research before you post a question on SA. I'm guessing there are many tutorials to show you what is missing.

Comment: PDO query is used.

Comment: This was based on a tutorial.

Comment: Why brackets around the table name and id value?

Comment: Do I need the single quotes?

Comment: What tutorial? Seems not a good one, if you want read the official PHP PDO manual there are enough examples: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Passing these values from the front-end and injecting them directly in a query is a very bad idea. You should use white-lists for the table- and column names and a prepared statement for the values.

Answer (score -1):

Is it because of we shouldn't put '' into the query?
I mean: 
`$query = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM ($questionTable) WHERE id = ($questionID)");`

Comment: So the way to extract a parameter's value is by enclosing it with parentheses? That is so weird.

Comment: The parentheses are useless. They only bloat the query.

Comment: How am I supposed to do it then?

Comment: @konyv12: The last time i write something like this is without parenthese. like SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE id = $id, but i'm sorry that i'm not sure is there the difference between i used and your case.